# What is the exact work, that the getchar() is doing?

Tags: c, struct, getchar

Here, if I don't use `getchar()` the output is misbehaving:

[image: Check here to see the output console]

What exactly is the `getchar()` doing here ?

And what is it holding until another input gets invoked ?

And how will the next input be invoked here in this case ?

My code:

```
//To take 3 students data using stucture which is user defined.
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
//#include<conio.h>
struct student
{
    char reg_number[200];
    char name[200];
    int marks_obt;
};
```

```
int main()
{
    struct student stud1,stud2,stud3;
    printf("Enter registration number of student 1 : ");
    gets(stud1.reg_number);
    printf("Enter name of student 1 : ");
    gets(stud1.name);
    printf("Enter marks of student 1 : ");
    scanf("%d",&stud1.marks_obt);
    system("cls");
        //getchar();
    printf("Enter registration number of student 2 : ");
    gets(stud2.reg_number);
    printf("Enter name of student 2 : ");
    gets(stud2.name);
    printf("Enter marks of student 2 : ");
    scanf("%d",&stud2.marks_obt);
    system("cls");
        //getchar();
    printf("Enter registration number of student 3 : ");
    gets(stud3.reg_number);
    printf("Enter name of student 3 : ");
    gets(stud3.name);
    printf("Enter marks of student 3 : ");
    scanf("%d",&stud3.marks_obt);
    system("cls");
    
    printf("ID of student 1 is %s \n Name of student 1 is %s \n Marks obtained by stdent 1 is %d",stud1.reg_number,stud1.name,stud1.marks_obt);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("ID of student 2 is %s \n Name of student 2 is %s \n Marks obtained by stdent 2 is %d",stud2.reg_number,stud2.name,stud2.marks_obt);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("ID of student 3 is %s \n Name of student 3 is %s \n Marks obtained by stdent 3 is %d",stud3.reg_number,stud3.name,stud3.marks_obt);
    //getch();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already comments and a correct answer that should be enough, but judging by your last comment it seems that you didn't yet understand what's going on.

This line:

```
scanf("%d",&stud1.marks_obt);
```

Parses an integer, for that you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, when you do that a `\n` is added to the `stdin` buffer, and remains there, ***it is not*** parsed by `scanf`.

After that:

```
gets(stud2.reg_number);
```

Will parse that `\n` character and store it in `stud2.reg_number`, and the program moves on.

When you use `getchar()`, it parses the `\n` and leaves the `stdin` buffer empty again so the `gets` has nothing to parse and waits for your input, correcting the problem, it's still a flimsy solution, but it works in this particular case.

Moral of the story, don't mix `scanf` with `gets`, `fgets` at least, since, as stated, `gets` was removed from the standard in C11. The reason why some compilers still support it is beyond me.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, [never use the `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used). It is deprecated from the C and C++ standards. The safe way would be to apply `fgets()`:

```
char input[128];
if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) == NULL) {
  // Oops... input was incorrectly given, handle the error
  return EXIT_FAILURE; // To quit
}

// Removing the trailing newline character
input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = 0;
```

You're facing an overlap when asking for another input from the user in the next `gets()` call because you hit the <kbd>Return</kbd> key as well when you finish typing with `scanf()`. A newline key is added at the end.

The `getchar()` takes the newline, so it is discarded and does the job you expect.